# Cannot access stage properties from a method?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scope, nullreferenceexception

I have an object on my stage, called obj.

I also have a class called "Physics" which contains a bunch of methods for physics, such as inertia, gravity, and bouncing off walls. In order to do some of these, I need access to the stage.stageWidth and stageHeight properties.

My code is as follows:

```
        public function wallBounce(obj)
    {
        this.stageRef = stageRef
        if (obj.x > stageRef.stageWidth || obj.x < 0)
        {
            obj.vX = (obj.vX * -1) * bounceConst
        }
    }
```

This is supposed to check if the object's x value is greater than the stageWidth or less than 0. When I run this code it says:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

I am a semi-newbie programmer who is completely self-taught and have no clue what is causing this. I spent a bit googling it, and I think it has something to do with scopes, but I don't know how to fix this, and barely even know what scopes really do.

Again, sorry if this a really stupid question, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.stageRef = stageRef;
```

I don't see any reference to `stageRef` from this function? Also, because you're working from within a class - `this.val` and `val` are the same thing. You may as well be going:

```
this.stageRef = this.stageRef;
```

Or

```
stageRef = stageRef;
```

The issue basically is `stageRef` is null - does this help? It seems you're meaning to say:

`this.stageRef = <some reference to stage youve defined somewhere else>;`

Seems odd to do it this way - as long as the object you're trying to call `wallBounce()` from is on the DisplayList, you'll be able to access the stage via `stage`. If you want to avoid errors in this function (maybe it runs once before it's actually been added to the DisplayList), then just put at the top:

```
if(!stage) return;
```

So:

```
public function wallBounce(obj:Object):void
{
    if(!stage) return;

    //this.stageRef = stageRef
    if (obj.x > stage.stageWidth || obj.x < 0)
    {
        obj.vX = (obj.vX * -1) * bounceConst
    }
}
```

`return` will essentially end the function on the spot.

As per comment:

Could make a static property in your Document Class that holds the stage. Like so:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip
    {
        // vars
        public static var stageRef:Stage;

        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function DocumentClass()
        {
            stageRef = stage;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can access the stage from your other classes like so:

```
public function wallBounce(obj:Object):void
{
    //this.stageRef = stageRef
    if (obj.x > DocumentClass.stageRef.stageWidth || obj.x < 0)
    {
        obj.vX = (obj.vX * -1) * bounceConst
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, but it's still not letting me access stage.stageHeight, which is really all I want to do. The this.stageref was something I used to try and fix it, but it obviously was in vain.

Comment: Hey sorry read over and my answer seemed harsh. Maybe in your document class try making a static reference to stage that you can use anywhere. I'll update my answer for an example.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much! I just tried this and it worked. I really do appreciate your help, especially with such a novice question.

Thanks :D!